# Issue with shortened arrows in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have a problem with arrow tips. I want to draw an arrow like the horizontal one in this image (this is just a MWE):

[image]

The position of the arrow tips is correct (the circle on the left must be over the NO-SO vertical line, and the tip on the right must end a few pt before the NE-SE vertical line). The problem is that if I use `shorten` the wawy line is a mess. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (NO) at (-2,+1.5) {NO};
  \node (SO) at (-2,-1.5) {SO};
  \node (NE) at (+2,+1.5) {NE};
  \node (SE) at (+2,-1.5) {SE};
  \draw [<->] (NO) -- node[coordinate] (O){} (SO);
  \draw [<->] (NE) -- node[coordinate] (E){} (SE);
  \draw [
      {Circle[width=8pt, length=8pt, open]}-{Triangle[scale=1.5]},
      decorate, decoration=snake, thick, shorten <=-4pt, shorten >= 4pt
    ] (O) -- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Bonus question: is there any way to shift horizontally the E and O nodes when they are defined as in my code, without defining auxiliary nodes?

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the bonus question, do you mean that you want to change where the arrow hits the node?

Comment: I mean that I want to change the node position instead of using shorten, but this would be just a workaround (I'd prefer to use shorten and fix the line isdue). Also, I need that for another picture

Comment: Sorry, I actually looked at the wrong nodes. Use for example `coordinate[right=10pt] (O)` to move `O` 10pt to the right.

Comment: How do I use that? Is it an option for `node` or does it replace `node`?

Comment: `coordinate` is short for `node[coordinate]`, so `coordinate[...] (O)` replaces `node[coordinate, ...] (O){}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution for your decoration is to add `pre length=4pt` and `post length=9pt`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (NO) at (-2,+1.5) {NO};
  \node (SO) at (-2,-1.5) {SO};
  \node (NE) at (+2,+1.5) {NE};
  \node (SE) at (+2,-1.5) {SE};
  \draw [<->] (NO) -- node[coordinate] (O){} (SO);
  \draw [<->] (NE) -- node[coordinate] (E){} (SE);
  \draw [
      {Circle[width=8pt, length=8pt, open]}-{Triangle[scale=1.5]},
      decorate, decoration={snake,pre length=4pt,post length=9pt}, thick, shorten <=-4pt, shorten >= 4pt
    ] (O) -- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For your bonus question, you could just add `xshift=-4pt` to the node options, but this still needs some `post`- and `pre length`.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (NO) at (-2,+1.5) {NO};
  \node (SO) at (-2,-1.5) {SO};
  \node (NE) at (+2,+1.5) {NE};
  \node (SE) at (+2,-1.5) {SE};
  \draw [<->] (NO) -- node[coordinate,xshift=-4pt] (O){} (SO);
  \draw [<->] (NE) -- node[coordinate,xshift=-4pt] (E){} (SE);
  \draw [
      {Circle[width=8pt, length=8pt, open]}-{Triangle[scale=1.5]},
      decorate, decoration={snake,pre length=8pt,post length=8pt}, thick] (O) -- (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In both cases the result looks (more or less) like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How did you get the post length value? By trials or did you calculate it somehow?

Comment: @Taekwondavide ashamed I admit by trial and error :)